# Celery not respecting BROKER_URL

Tags: redis, celery

I tried to search the relative questions on stackoverflow and on google but didn't find something which could solve my issue.

I have BROKER_URL set in my /etc/default/celeryd configuration as redis.
BROKER_URL="redis://localhost:6379"

But when I start /etc/init.d/celeryd start

it says: "ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672//:"

Also on the docs page I saw about celeryconfig.py. I don't understand why should I have two config files? /etc/default/celeryd is there for configuration.

Comment: disrespectful celery

Answer (score 4):

You can try `CELERY_BROKER_URL` instead of `BROKER_URL` if you set the namespace like `app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")`.

Ref: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/history/whatsnew-4.0.html#latentcall-django-admonition

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're not setting `broker` when defining your app.  This one bit me when I copied and pasted code from the tutorial.  It took me hours to realize I was overriding my own configuration with this line:

```
app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')
```

It should say this:

```
app = Celery('tasks')
```

Comment: this does not fix it, neither does setting app = Celery('intro', broker='redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0')