# Celery: ignoring BROKER_URL in config file

Tags: celery, config, configuration-files

My question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19462521/celery-not-respecting-broker-url), but more detailed.

The problem is that I have a `BROKER_URL` set in my Celery config file, but that isn't reflected in and I *am* loading the config: I checked, and it *is* being loaded - in fact, other constants defined there are being set, just not `BROKER_URL`.

This appears to be a bug, but I wanted to be sure.

---

**`celeryconfig.py`:**

```
BROKER_URL = "amqp://user:password@remote.server.com:5672//vhost"

CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
```

(`JSON` is being used as the serializer, not `Pickle`, so I know this is working.)

**`app.py`:**

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')
app.config_from_object('celeryconfig')
```

**Invoking the Worker:**

```
celery -A app.app worker -l info
```

But then I get this:

```
[2013-11-12 11:20:51,610: INFO/MainProcess] consumer: Connected to amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672//.
```

---

I tried breaking up `BROKER_URL`, but to no avail:

```
BROKER_TRANSPORT = 'amqp'
BROKER_USER = 'user'
BROKER_PASSWORD = 'password'
BROKER_HOST = 'remote.server.com'
BROKER_PORT = 5672
BROKER_VHOST = '/vhost'
```

Interestingly, it does work when I explicitly set the `BROKER_URL` in `app.py`:

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')
app.config_from_object('celeryconfig')
app.conf.BROKER_URL = "amqp://user:password@remote.server.com:5672//vhost"
```

Comment: Note that breaking up the broker url is deprecated, and will be removed in celery 4: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/internals/deprecation.html

Answer (score 21):

Of course, I realized what I'd done wrong immediately after finishing this question, but I still posted it because someone might find it useful.

My problem is that I copied and pasted code from the tutorial (*facepalm).

I'm overriding the config file when I define the app with a `broker` arg:

```
app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')
```

Simply remove that:

```
app = Celery('tasks')
```

Tada!  Everything works fine... and I learned a valuable lesson.

Comment: well, I was guilty of the same thing! Thanks for coming back to update this

Answer (score 8):

Just for clarification because you are using this:

```
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
```

You must add the `CELERY_` prefix to the `BROKER_URL` entry in your celeryconfig.py:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "amqp://user:password@remote.server.com:5672//vhost"

CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for anyone else with a similar issue, I ran into a similar problem with a different cause.

I'm using celery with django on heroku, but in my dev environment I am using [django-environ](https://github.com/joke2k/django-environ) to populate environment variables from a file.

I forgot to preface my celery worker command with `DJANGO_READ_DOT_ENV_FILE=1`

So I went from:

`celery -A myapp worker -l info`

to

`DJANGO_READ_DOT_ENV_FILE=1 celery -A myapp worker -l info`

Silly, but a good reminder.  Hope it saves someone some time.

Answer (score 0):

I was going absolutely crazy on this. Celery was ignoring my Django settings even though I followed the docs to the t.

I ran

```
celery -A celery worker -l info
```

I put a breakpoint() in my common/celery.py file and realised that it was not the celery app that was being run. I had to run the below instead:

```
celery -A my_project_name worker -l info
```

Answer (score 0):

I had next directory:

> config
> -__init__.py
> -celery.py
> -settings.py
> -...

**init**.py had:

```
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

celery.py had:

```
import os
from celery import Celery
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger



os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'config.settings')

app = Celery('mail')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks()


logger = get_task_logger(__name__)
```

So the reason why celery was running with default broker_url amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672// was not correct runnig worker command.
You have to run:

```
celery -A config worker -l INFO --logfile="celery.log"
```

not that:

```
celery -A celery worker -l INFO --logfile="celery.log"
```

-A parametr has to receive directory name with where **init**.py and celery.py in.