# celery won't connect to rabbitmq broker for kubernetes

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, celery, kubernetes

I am currently trying to deploy a basic task queue and frontend using celery, rabbitmq and flower on Kubernetes (and minikube).  I am following the example here:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/release-1.3/examples/celery-rabbitmq

I can get everything to work following the instructions; however, when I run `docker build` on the `Dockerfile` in `./celery-app-add`, push the image to my own repository and replace `endocode/celery-app-add` with `<mine>/celery-app-add`, I can't get the example to run anymore.  I am assuming that the `Dockerfile` in source control is wrong because if I pull the `endocode/celery-app-add` image and run bash in the image, it loads in as the `root` user (as opposed to `user` with `<mine>/celery-app-add` `Dockerfile`).

After booting up all of the containers and services, I can see the following in the logs:

`2016-08-18T21:05:44.846591547Z AttributeError: 'ChannelPromise' object has no attribute '__value__'`

The celery logs show:

`2016-08-19T01:38:49.933659218Z [2016-08-19 01:38:49,933: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@rabbit:5672//: [Errno -2] Name or service not known.`

If I echo `RABBITMQ_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST` within the container, it appears as the same host as indicated in the `rabbitmq-service` after running `kubectl get services`.

I am not really sure where to go from here.  Any suggestions are appreciated.  Also, I added `USER root` (won't run this in production, don't worry) to my `Dockerfile` and still ran into the same issues above. `docker history endocode/celery-app-add` hasn't been too helpful either.

Comment: It seems that whenever I try to run the celery worker, the config application is not being read and the worker keeps trying to connect to `amqp://guest:**@rabbit:5672//:` instead of the correct broker service host.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem is based around this celery [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19938719/celery-ignoring-broker-url-in-config-file).  Celery prefers to use `CELERY_BROKER_URL` over anything that can be set in the app configuration. To fix this, I unset `CELERY_BROKER_URL` in the `Dockerfile` and it picked up my configuration correctly.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. But couldnt fix it after using `CELERY_BROKER_URL` as well. Any thoughts?

Comment: Also, I've checked the shared link as well. I'm not passing it explicitly as well. How can I debug it?